# Ajax request with amplify firing restful service two times

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, xmlhttprequest

I am facing one strange issue with AJAX request which using fired via amplify. The issue is API request is getting fired two times and I am able to see first XHR in browser's network under developer tool but no trace of second XHR. Below is the code snippets of both client side and service side (ASP.NET MVC).

```js
//Intialized amlifier

amplify.request.define('result', 'ajax', {
  url: '/api/Result',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
  dataType: 'json',
  timeout: 720000,
  type: 'POST'
});


//API request invoker
var getResult = function (request, callback) {
       
  request = JSON.stringify(request);

    return amplify.request({
      resourceId: "result",
      data: request,
      success: function (data) {
        callback(data);
      }
  });
};
```

```cs
//MVC Controller
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public class ResultController : ApiController
{
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public Response Post(RequestDataVM jsonRequest)
    {              
       return Response.ProcessRequest(jsonRequest); //This is getting called two times
    }
}
```

Comment: The Configuration part looks ok. You have to cross check the place you are calling the request invoke method.

Comment: Thanks for reply @RJK, I have verified the place which request gets invoked and also no trace under network details in browser developer tools. PFB stack trace of this exception:

Comment: "Error: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'https://www.maskedhost.com/api/Result'.
    at Error (native)
    at Object.send (https://www.maskedhost.com/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4:17879)
    at Function.ajax (https://www.maskedhost.com/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4:15044)
    at Object.result (https://www.maskedhost.com/Scripts/amplify.request.js:173:5)
    at Object.amplify.request

Comment: (https://www.maskedhost.com/Scripts/amplify.request.js:81:50)
    at Object.getResult (https://www.maskedhost.com/Scripts/resultView/result.dataService.js:118:24)
    at Object.getResultData (https://www.maskedhost.com/Scripts/resultView/resultModel.js:130:39)
    at getResultData (https://www.maskedhost.com/Scripts/Report/reportViewModel.js:935:25)